# Determine the values of m and n for which the function $f(x)= mx^4 +nx^3 + 68x^2 −x− 6$ gives a remainder of zero when divided by (2x+ 1) and (4x− 1)

Tags: functions

I have tried for a long time and cannot solve this. Any examples I find removes a variable when eliminating but with this question, it doesn't seem that simple.

Comment: Do you know the factor theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The factor theorem states that if $(ax-b)$ is a factor of $f(x)$, then $f(\frac{b}{a})=0$

In this case $f(\frac{-1}{2})=0$ and $f(\frac{1}{4})=0$.

Substituting these in should give you two equations in terms of $m$ and $n$, which you can then solve simultaneously.

Have fun!

Comment: Also, if anyone knows how to make my fractions look a bit cleaner, that would be nice!

Comment: I do understand factor theorem but I am having trouble eliminating the equations afterwards

Comment: In that case, I recommend watching this video about simultaneous equations: https://youtu.be/Vw5_LV2n-GI

Comment: You may have to multiply the equations by a constant to remove the fractional coefficients and try to get the constant on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

By the factot theorem, we have that $f(-\frac{1}{2})$ and $f(\frac{1}{4})=0$ and so:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{256}m+\frac{1}{64}n-2=0
\\ \frac{1}{16}m-\frac{1}{8}n+\frac{23}{2}=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: I think your substitutions are incorrect. I made a suggested edit.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Corrected.